# Accessing elements in maya's range notation

Tags: python, maya

okay its probably a stupid question, but I just can't see or find the solution. I'm working on a UV map in Maya and need to set translation values via Python scripting. I however can't pick a specific element in a list when the returned object is in range notation. Example:

So, first I select an edge and convert to UV-Points:

```
cmds.select(name+'.e[0:4]', add=True)
cmds.select(cmds.polyListComponentConversion(fe=True, tuv=True), add=False)
selection = cmds.ls(sl=True)
print(selection)
```

Now when I print this, I get:

```
[u'pSphere1.map[0:1]', u'pSphere1.map[4]', u'pSphere1.map[6]', u'pSphere1.map[8]', u'pSphere1.map[10]']
```

Now there is my problem. Inside the list are 5 elements, however, 6 points are selected, because the first element is in range notation.

When I iterate over this list like:

```
p = 0
cmds.select( clear=True )
for pUV in selection:
    cmds.select(pUV, add=False)
    cmds.polyEditUV(uValue=vList[p][0], vValue=vList[p][1], r=True)
    p = p+1
```

or query like:

```
var = cmds.polyEditUV( query=True )
```

then this is not working, as the first object is selecting not one UV but two, because the string `pSphere1.map[0:1]` defines a range. What I need is to split the range into single UVs or being able to access sub-elemets of this range, however using `ls` just returns a string with range notation again.

I could parse the string, look for a colon and then extract the values before and after the colon, reinterpret as integers and use this for iteration, but I am sure there must be a simpler way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ls` with the `flatten` option to get the lists down to isolated entries without ranges:

```
compressed  = cmds.ls('pCube1.vtx[*]')
print compressed
# [u'pCube1.vtx[0:7]']
expanded = cmds.ls('pCube1.vtx[*]', flatten=True)
print expanded
 # [u'pCube1.vtx[0]', u'pCube1.vtx[1]', u'pCube1.vtx[2]', u'pCube1.vtx[3]', u'pCube1.vtx[4]', u'pCube1.vtx[5]', u'pCube1.vtx[6]', u'pCube1.vtx[7]']
```

The other option is the [`filterExpand`](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/CHS/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/filterExpand.html) command, which uses a somewhat cryptic series of codes to select components:

```
 print cmds.filterExpand(compressed, sm = 31)
 # [u'pCube1.vtx[0]', u'pCube1.vtx[1]', u'pCube1.vtx[2]', u'pCube1.vtx[3]', u'pCube1.vtx[4]', u'pCube1.vtx[5]', u'pCube1.vtx[6]', u'pCube1.vtx[7]']
```

`filterExpand` is particularly useful for mixed selections since the supplied mask value (see the link for the codes) will limit a mixed selection to only one component type at a time.

Comment: Embarrassing, I completely overlooked that flag. Thanks. I marked as answered and will up-vote as soon as my rep is sufficient.